# What operating system can I use to turn my old computer into a home server?

Tags: operating-systems, home-server

I have a old desktop computer that I want to make a home server for file sharing purposes. It has 512 MB RAM and few GB of hard drive. Which operating system should be reasonable for this kind of slow system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[FreeNAS](http://freenas.org/) or [OpenFiler](http://openfiler.com/)  Both are designed for sharing files and both are free.

I use FreeNAS, it is easy for me and I like the features.  I say give them both a try.

Comment: I can give it a try. My other 3 laptops have Windows 7 and Win XP installed. They will be accessing the old machine server for files and stuff.

Comment: My Windows machines have no problem with FreeNAS.  After configuring your drive(s), you need to enable the CIFS service, then next to the CIFS settings tab is a Shares tab.  That is where you share the drive(s).  Their webpage has some good walkthroughs (http://freenas.org/documentation:setup_and_user_guide:cifs).  What I like is you can have a recycle bin on the shares, and you don't need to do updates and AV as much as another Windows box.  Just turn it on and it works.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @ScottMcClenning I think Ubuntu would be a good option too.  Especially with a 512 ram limit.

Answer (score 2):

Only a few Gigs?

A linux distro would work I guess but adding even a 40 gig in there would greatly expand your options.

Comment: I will double check on gigs but the hard drive space might be okay.

Comment: It's easy enough to pop in a "new" old harddrive to increase the OS disc space.

Comment: probably best to look for a "server" version instead of a typical "desktop" version of whatever distro looks good (ie, Ubuntu server instead of normal Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I run a web/file server on a PIII 450 with 640mb of ram. For a 'pure' fileserver, freenas is nice, else going for a cli only install of ubuntu works well. Hardwarewise, you'd need at least one network port, naturally, and you could set up the box headless, doing admin tasks via openssh. I'm using less than 100 mb of ram right now with a file/web server based off ubuntu so... yeah, it would probably work

Answer (score 0):

An OS such as [Minix](http://www.minix3.org/) would fit, but it's not clear if you can do any more than learn about OS internals.

This is what Minix was designed for.